# Percorrer string com PHP e retornar valores pesquisados

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Estou desenvolvendo um script que seja capaz de localizar determinadas *tags* em uma string e retorne todas encontradas.

O padrão da *tag* será: `[exibebanner id="300"]`, sendo que dentro de `id="int"` sempre será um valor inteiro.

O script abaixo faz a pesquisa e retorna todos os valores de `id` encontrados:

```
    $str = '[exibebanner id="300"] <br/>é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica  <br/><b>[exibebanner id="40"]</b> e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou um<br/> <b>[exibebanner id="90"]</b>';   


preg_match_all('/[exibebanner [^]]*id=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
    echo PHP_EOL . $value;
}
```

RETORNO:

```
300 40 90
```

O retorno que preciso é o seguinte:

```
[exibebanner id="300"] [exibebanner id="40"] [exibebanner id="90"]
```

Com esses valores poderei aplicar uma função que encontre essas ocorrências dentro da string e troque por uma função do tipo: `add_banner([exibebanner id="40"])`

Não tenho experiência com expressões regulares e preciso de uma orientação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma alteração no regex para o valor do `id` e funcionou, o `\d` pega apenas valores numéricos, e a expressão `{,}` se refere a 1 ou mais ocorrências.

```
preg_match_all('/(\[exibebanner id="\d{1,}"\])/i', $str, $matches);
```

Uma sugestão para quando estiver utilizando regex testar em sites como https://regexr.com/

Veja este caso aqui: https://regexr.com/4pcqb

Comment: Para "uma ou mais ocorrências", o mais comum - e mais simples também - é usar `+`, então ficaria `\d+`. O quantificador `{x,}` é usado quando o valor de `x` é maior que 1 (pois aí não há outra alternativa)

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro acho que vale explicar porque sua regex não funcionou.

Basicamente, os colchetes `[]` possuem significado especial em regex: servem para determinar uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Por exemplo, `[abc]` é uma expressão regular que significa "a letra `a`, **ou** a letra `b`, **ou** a letra `c`" (apenas uma delas, qualquer uma serve). E a ordem não importa, portanto `[abc]`, `[bac]` e `[cab]` são equivalentes ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/RV5hvR/2/) um exemplo).

Ou seja, na sua regex, o trecho `[exibebanner [^]` significa "a letra `e`, **ou** a letra `x`, **ou** a letra `i` ..., **ou** um espaço, **ou** o caractere `[`, **ou** o caractere `^`". Veja que as letras `e`, `b`, e `n` aparecem mais de uma vez, o que é redundante. Mas o que importa é que todo este trecho **corresponde a apenas um caractere** (qualquer um que esteja indicado dentro dos colchetes - [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/mhyZzG) um exemplo). Para que a regex considere os próprios caracteres `[` e `]`, devemos escapá-los com `\` (ou seja, devemos escrevê-los como `\[` e `\]`).

Depois temos `]*`. Aqui temos uma "pegadinha". Como não há um colchete de abertura correspondente, a engine interpreta que este é o próprio caractere `]` (ou seja, neste caso não precisa escapá-lo com `\`). E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Isso quer dizer que se tiver um `]` serve, se tiver vários `]]]]` também serve, e mesmo se não tiver nenhum, também serve (afinal, são **zero** ou mais ocorrências de `]`) - [veja aqui](https://ideone.com/LzcXHX) um exemplo.

Isso tudo explica como foi feito o *match* desta regex. O trecho `[exibebanner [^]` capturou o espaço em branco antes de `id=` (veja que há um espaço dentro dos colchetes, então ele é um dos caracteres que correspondem à esta classe). Já o trecho `]*` não pegou nenhum caractere (pois `*` também aceita zero ocorrências do caractere), e em seguida o restante da regex pegou do `id=` para a frente ([aqui](https://regex101.com/r/RaJB1M/4/) você pode ver melhor o que cada trecho da regex pega).

Então a primeira coisa a fazer é escapar os colchetes com `\`. Há outros detalhes a serem melhorados, uma alternativa seria fazer assim:

```
preg_match_all('/\[exibebanner id=["\']\d+["\']\]/i', $str, $matches);

foreach ($matches[0] as $value) {
    echo PHP_EOL . $value;
}
```

Removi o `$key` do `foreach` porque não estava sendo usado. A saída é:

```
[exibebanner id="300"]
[exibebanner id="40"]
[exibebanner id="90"]
```

Mudei outros detalhes na sua regex.

Primeiro as aspas (logo depois de `id=`): você tinha usado `["|\']`, mas como já vimos antes, os colchetes definem uma classe de caracteres, então este trecho pega os caracteres `"`, `|` e `'`. Esse é um erro bem comum ao usar regex, pois o caractere `|` é usado para [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), mas dentro de colchetes ele "perde seus poderes" e se torna um caractere comum. Por isso, se você tivesse algo como `id=|300`, a regex encontraria um *match* ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/ALwTPs/2/)). Então eu removi o `|` daí e deixei somente `["\']`.

Depois você tinha usado `[^"|\']`, que é uma classe de caracteres negada (o `^` logo depois do `[` diz que eu quero os caracteres que **não** estão na lista). Ou seja, ela vai pegar qualquer caractere que **não** seja `"`, `|` e `'`. Isso quer dizer que se o texto tiver `id="abc"` ou `id="!@#$%&"`, a regex também encontrará um *match* ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/ALwTPs/4/)).

Como você disse que o `id` sempre é um número inteiro, então [seja mais específico](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want) e use o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`, que considera somente dígitos. Eu também usei o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" (a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/423018/112052) usou `{1,}`, que [é equivalente](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), mas `+` é o mais usual para este caso - usar `{x,}` ou `{x,y}` faz mais sentido quando as quantidades possuem valores diferentes, como por exemplo `{3,}` para indicar "no mínimo 3 ocorrências").

Outro detalhe é que você usou a [*flag* `i`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (a letra `i` logo depois da segunda `/`, no final da regex), que indica que a regex é *case insensitive*, ou seja, não diferencia letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Por isso, se o texto tiver `[EXIBEbanner Id="123"]`, ele também será encontrado. Se quiser que somente letras minúsculas sejam aceitas, basta remover o `i` da expressão.

Repare também que removi os parênteses, pois eles não são necessários aqui. Você pode simplesmente pegar `$matches[0]`, que possui todos os trechos encontrados. [Os parênteses formam grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e no seu caso, como só tinha um par de parênteses, eles eram o primeiro grupo, e por isso estavam disponíveis em `$matches[1]`. Mas neste caso a regex já pega todo o trecho que você precisa e não há a necessidade de criar um grupo.

---

Mas a regex acima ainda tem um problema.

Como você usou `["\']` para as aspas, entendo que o texto pode ter tanto aspas duplas quanto aspas simples. Só que a regex não verifica se o caractere que foi usado na abertura é o mesmo do fechamento. Isso quer dizer que ela encontra um *match* em casos como `[exibebanner id="90']`.

Para evitar este problema, podemos usar um grupo de captura (agora sim ele é necessário), juntamente com [*backreferences*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
preg_match_all('/\[exibebanner id=(["\'])\d+\1\]/i', $str, $matches);
// restante do código igual
```

Eu coloco os parênteses em volta das aspas de abertura (logo depois de `id=`), e isso cria o primeiro grupo de captura. Depois eu uso a *backreference* `\1`, que significa "o mesmo texto que foi capturado no grupo 1". Neste caso, será o caractere correspondente às aspas de abertura (`"` ou `'`). Isso garante que a regex só pega os casos em que as aspas de abertura e fechamento usam o mesmo caractere, ignorando casos como `id="90'`.

Claro que se os dados são controlados e você "sabe" que as aspas sempre estão corretas (não existem casos como `id="90'`), aí não precisa de tanto preciosismo. O ideal é [ser o mais específico possível](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want), mas encontrando um equilíbrio entre a complexidade da regex e a acurácia da mesma nos dados sendo analisados.